# Php Phalcon - Select statement does not return anything

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I am working in PHP Phalcon. I am using the XAMPP server. I am working with phql in MVC. I have a table named "Patient_Info" and a class named "PatientInfo". I have used the insert statement to enter data into the table and it works fine. Now I want to select data at a particular patient_id.
The model class is here:

```
  class PatientInfo extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
    {
        private  $BP;
        private  $Temperature;
        private  $Medical_Info;
        private  $Patient_ID;       //foreign key
        private  $DateOfMeeting; 

public function setDateOfMeeting($value)
    {
        $this->DateOfMeeting = $value;
    }

    public function getDateOfMeeting()
    {
        return $this->DateOfMeeting;
    }
    }
```

The class also has other similar getters and setters which I have not included in this post. As for the table, it has columns with the same names as the attributes of the model class but there is one extra column, the Unique_ID, the primary key. It is set to auto increment with every new entry in the table.

Now this is my select statement:

```
 $select_query = "Select "
                            ."PatientInfo.BP,"
                            ."PatientInfo.Temperature,"
                            ."PatientInfo.Medical_Info,"
                            ."PatientInfo.Patient_ID,"
                            ."PatientInfo.DateOfMeeting FROM PatientInfo WHERE Patient_ID = :pid:";

        $patient1 = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($select_query,array('pid' => '4gt')); 

//my echo statement
 $this->view->setVar("patient_id", $patient1->Patient_ID);
```

In the corresponding view I have this echo statement:

```
 <div>Patient's ID: <?php echo $patient_id; ?></div>
```

When I run the code, nothing shows in the place of echo. It's just blank like "Patient's ID:" That's it.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have also tried to make the attribute public, it doesn't work

Comment: I saw this syntax from the phalcon documentation here http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->view->setVar("patient_id", $patient1[0]->Patient_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the commas out of the double quotes and remove the concatenation dots:

```
$select_query = "Select PatientInfo.BP, PatientInfo.Temperature, PatientInfo.Medical_Info, PatientInfo.Patient_ID, PatientInfo.DateOfMeeting FROM PatientInfo WHERE Patient_ID = :pid:";
```

Your XAMPP should have phpMyAdmin.  Run the Query in phpMyAdmin and see if you get a result or an error.

Or after the `executeQuery` statement check for an error.

Comment: I had that before. When it didn't work for better readability i made it into lines

Comment: And what do you mean take the commas out of the double quotes?